# AJAX request sometimes out of order

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I'm having trouble with POST and GET request. On my server side right up until the moment before I send I have what I expect but then on my client side I get things out of order. For example these two should be in the reverse order I have here:

Sending from server{"grid":["","","","","","","","",""],"winner":""}
Received at server: {"grid":["X","","","","","","","",""],"winner":""}

```js
function sendData(json) {
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/ttt",
           data: json,
           dataType: "json",
           success: receiveData()
        });
    }

function receiveData() {
   
    var response = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ttt",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(){
            grid = response.responseJSON;
            console.log("Receved at client: " + JSON.stringify(grid));
        }
    });
   console.log("Also after receiving " + JSON.stringify(grid));
}
```

gives me:
Also after receiving {"grid":["X","","","","","","","",""],"winner":""}
Receved at client: {"grid":["X","O","","","","","","",""],"winner":""}

I think this may two different problems. One for getting things out of order and another for why my grid doesnt reflect the changes after my success clause function in my GET request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making a common mistake.  You need to use a function reference without the parens here for `receiveData`.  Change this:

```
function sendData(json) {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/ttt",
       data: json,
       dataType: "json",
       success: receiveData()
    });
}
```

to this:

```
function sendData(json) {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/ttt",
       data: json,
       dataType: "json",
       success: receiveData     // no parens here
    });
}
```

When you include the parens, it calls the function IMMEDIATELY and puts the return value from the function as the success handler and thus you see them run out of order.  You want to pass a function reference to it can be called later.  A function reference is the function's name without the parens.

---

It also appears like you have another mistake in `receiveData()`.  You are using the wrong thing for the response.  The response is not returns from `$.ajax()`.  The response is passed to the success handler.

I don't know exactly what your response is supposed to look like, but change this:

```
function receiveData() {

    var response = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ttt",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(){
            grid = response.responseJSON;
            console.log("Receved at client: " + JSON.stringify(grid));
        }
    });
   console.log("Also after receiving " + JSON.stringify(grid));
}
```

to something like this:

```
function receiveData() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ttt",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            grid = response.responseJSON;
            console.log("Received at client: " + JSON.stringify(grid));
            console.log("Also after receiving " + JSON.stringify(grid));
        }
    });
}
```

And, because your ajax calls are asynchronous, you also had this statement `console.log("Also after receiving " + JSON.stringify(grid));` in the wrong place.  If you want to see the results of the grid after you've modified it, then you have to put that inside the success handler.

---

**Summary of Fixes**

1. Change `success: receiveData()` to `success: receiveData`.
2. Use `response` as it is passed to the success handler.
3. Put `console.log()` to see final results inside the `success` handler.

---

It appears that you may not fully understand how ajax calls are asynchronous and what that really means for your programming.  I'd suggest doing some searching and reading on that topic.  Learning that now will save you a lot of agony as you develop.

Comment: Thank you very much that was it. You're right I going to spend some time learning about ajax and how to use it.